# How does these lines of code eat all my RAM? and How do I fix it?

Tags: python

I want to modify charactors not supported by python xml parser like this"&eacute" or "×", so I write a python script to process it.
So it will become  "José Meseguer" to "Jose Meseguer". 
It works on a sampled small xml file, but on the original 2GB xml file, the  out of memory error pops up.

I tried o.write(line) as follows, but it seems that the memory couldn't hold that amount of data, and my IDE pops
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Output/dblp/preprocess.py", line 11, in <module>
    line = line.replace(line[index1: index2 + 1], line[index1 + 1])
MemoryError`.

```
f = open("dblp.xml")
o = open("dblp_processed.xml", 'w')

for line in f:
    flag = line.find('&') != -1 and line.find(';') != -1
    if flag:
        index = 0
        while flag:
            index1 = line.find('&', index)
            index2 = line.find(';', index)
            line = line.replace(line[index1: index2 + 1], line[index1 + 1])
            index = index1 + 1
            flag = line.find('&', index) != -1 and line.find(';', index) != -1
        o.write(line)
    else:
        o.write(line)

f.close()
o.close()
```

And I tried this code on my school server, it took almost 200GB and still going.

```
f = open("dblp_sample.xml")
o = open("dblp_processed.xml", 'w')

o_lines = list()
for line in f:
    flag = line.find('&') != -1 and line.find(';') != -1
    if flag:
        index = 0
        while flag:
            index1 = line.find('&', index)
            index2 = line.find(';', index)
            line = line.replace(line[index1: index2 + 1], line[index1 + 1])
            index = index1 + 1
            flag = line.find('&', index) != -1 and line.find(';', index) != -1
        o_lines.append(line)
    else:
        o_lines.append(line)

o.writelines(o_lines)
f.close()
o.close()
```

Comment: You… keep all lines in `o_lines`?

Comment: Why do you store more than one line in memory at a time? Read one line from input, transform it, write the transformed version of that one line to output. Don't even bother trying to keep a list; there's no reason to do so.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry about that, I tried o.write(), it didn't work. And does write() function store all the lines in buffer and write them all at once?

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't work"? If the problem is that you were expecting content to show up in the file *immediately* without flushing or closing the handle, then that's just a problem of inappropriate expectations.

Comment: `write()` does not store *all* content in memory to later write at once, no; even when buffering is enabled, it buffers only up to a certain amount of storage (often something like 32kb), using far less RAM than you do here.

Comment: Please show us your *full* implementation that used `o.write()`, not just the single line that failed and the exception it threw. If you still had `o_lines` in it, then the obvious problem is/was still present.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your explanation, I mean i tried to use write() fucntion, but it still goes out of memory. Using o_lines to store is my orinigal thought. The error with write() function implemented is 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Output/dblp/preprocess.py", line 11, in <module>
    line = line.replace(line[index1: index2 + 1], line[index1 + 1])
MemoryError'.

Comment: Given the error you had in the non-`o_lines`-based implementation, it looks like there's a specific line of input that was throwing off your logic. A good place to start would be identifying that line, and instrumenting your code to log the transformations within your inner loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry for that, I've edited my question above with different implementations I've tried.

Comment: ...so, if you print each line to stdout before transforming it, what's the content of the line that the first version (without `o_lines`) fails on? And given that content, can you reproduce the same error feeding it *only* that line and no others? If so, that lets you build a [mcve], a completely standalone reproducer that lets us create the bug ourselves (and test our proposed fixes) without needing to have your 2GB input file.

Comment: FYI: If entities that are not supported by XML are being inserted into your data, I'd argue that the problem is on the other side.  I know in "the real world" we have to deal with things, but I'd also see about having whomever is creating the original data does a better job of putting it together and making sure the data in conformant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I'll try that. And just another peoblem, the xml file size is 2GB, is it normal for it to take more than 12GB with this code? Is there any place in the code that consumes huge amount of memory? Because from my understanding if I process it line by line it shouldn't take that amount of memory.

Comment: @ZeruZhang, correct, if you process line-by-line *and don't retain content in memory*, you shouldn't need more than one line plus regular Python overhead (and some extra space so the garbage collector doesn't have to run too often). What I suspect is that you have a logic bug where your inner loop never ends and keeps transforming a single line into continually longer versions, but to reproduce that, we'd want to have actual data it happens for in hand. Rafael's answer is in line with that guess, too.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Yes, the problem occurs when I try to parse the xml file with elementTree, but in my environment, character like "&eacute" will raise error. So I tried to replace these charactors with default encoding.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While trying to reproduce the error on huge data, I want to point out that I've tried with sampled data with hundreds of records, it work as expect.

Comment: @ZeruZhang I understand that. :-)  What I mean is that you should report the issue to the creator of the XML file because they're producing a non-conformant XML file.  Better to fix the problem at the source than jump through hoops to fix a problem that every other consumer of the data will have to handle too. :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As Rafael mentioned below, the index2 and index1 are not guarded with a check, which casues the infinite loop. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: @ZeruZhang, "anyway"? Part of the point of getting you to build a [mcve] is guiding you to find the bug yourself. That's *better* than finding it for you, because you gain experience. :) (If there's a language barrier here -- "thank you anyway" is mildly insulting to some native English speakers, because it implies that what someone is being thanked for was insubstantive or not actually helpful).

Answer (score 2):

First, Python has a [built-in html module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) that you can use to replace HTML entities:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&eacute &times;')
'é ×'
```

Second, you only operate on one line at a time, so you can write one line at a time instead of storing them all:

```
import html

with open("dblp_sample.xml") as f, open("dblp_processed.xml", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as o:
    for line in f:
        o.write(html.unescape(line))
```

The loop can also be written as:

```
o.writelines(map(html.unescape, f))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the problem occurs when I try to parse the xml file with elementTree, special charactor like "&eacute" will raise a error. Is there a way of letting elementTree support that kind of encoding?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are assuming that index2 is always greater than index1, and that's not necessarily true. If index2 is smaller than index1, you will add line[index1 + 1] after all characters in a line (due to replace), which will double its size for each time it happens.

For instance:

```
a = 'aaaabbbccdeeeee'
b = a.replace(a[1:5],a[2])
output of b: 'aabbccdeeeee'
```

Now:

```
b= a.replace(a[5:1],a[2])
output of b: 'aaaaaaaaabababacacadaeaeaeaeaea'
```

And the above code could go on forever in an endless loop. Since the line would keep getting longer, we would never reach its end.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case. Based on my observation on the sampled data, "&" and ";" always show up in pair, but some where in the orinigal file ";" is ahead of "&", which causes infinite loop, because index1 and index2 on that line is unresonablely huge.